# Partial answer to a question

Tags: discussion

Suppose a user posts a question about a topic and then asks multiple questions regarding the same topic.

> [TOPIC]
>
> > Question 1: ... 
> >     Question 2: ... 
> >     etc.

and suppose I only know the answer for only 1 question.

Then should I write my reply as an answer or as a comment?
What about the situation where I know more than 1 answer but not for all of them?

Example: this question itself. (Recursive)

Comment: Same question was asked on SF: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6440/answering-part-of-a-question

Comment: @kasperd, sorry didn't know that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ideally a user would post only one question, but sometimes there are closely related questions which it doesn't make sense to post separately. If this is not the case, politely suggest to the poster that breaking up his post into multiple posts would be a good idea.

> suppose I only know the answer for only 1 question.
>   Then should I write my reply as an answer or as a comment?

As an answer, I think. At least, that is what I do. A comment is for non-answers.

> What about the situation where I know more than 1 answer but not for all of them?

Answer whatever you can answer.

Comment: thank you for clarifying this